# React img element attributes type definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { SFC } from 'react'; 
interface ImgProps extends ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>{

}

export const Slide: SFC<{
  src: Pick<ImgProps, "src">,
  alt: Pick<ImgProps, "alt">
}> =({
  src,
  alt
}) => {
  return(
    <IMG src={src} alt={alt}/>
  )
}
```

Hi, I want to make **img** tag as a react component and props might be src, and alt. 
I'm using typescript with react, how can I define interface or types for SFC / FC  as a generic type?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. You want `Slide`'s props to be generic? What about them would need a generic parameter?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. 
What I'm trying is  like 
```
  const Slide: FC <{ src : ?, alt: ? , someImgAttribute: ? }> = ({}) => ... 
```
don't know what proper types for src, alt or some img Attributes I want to use as a props.

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase tags (`<img/>`) become HTML tags, uppercase tags (`<Img/>`) are referencing to variables or functions.

Answer (score 0):

With React 18 something like this that uses a type might be a solution.

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, ImgHTMLAttributes } from 'react'; 

interface ImgProps extends ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>{
}

type SlideProps = Pick<ImgProps, "src" | "alt">;

export const Slide: FunctionComponent<SlideProps> = ({src, alt}) => {
  return (
    <img src={src} alt={alt}/>
  );
};
```